Community bulletin's "Featured" header should be a header instead of a list item
The community bulletin has a header ("Featured on Meta" for non-meta sites, "Featured" on meta sites) followed by a list of posts. As of right now, it looks like this on Meta Stack Exchange:

However, the page's markup does not have a header followed by a list. The header is inside the <ul> as another <li>. Its header-ness comes from a class, s-sidebarwidget--header:
<div class="s-sidebarwidget s-sidebarwidget__yellow s-anchors s-anchors__grayscale mb16" data-tracker="cb=1">
    <ul class="s-sidebarwidget--content s-sidebarwidget__items p0">
        <li class="s-sidebarwidget--header">
            Featured
        </li>
        <li class="s-sidebarwidget--item d-flex px16">
            <div class="flex--item1 fl-shrink0">
<div class="favicon favicon-stackexchangemeta" title="Meta Stack Exchange"></div>            </div>
            <div class="flex--item wmn0 ow-break-word">
                <a href="https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/404909/stack-overflow-jobs-is-expanding-to-more-countries?cb=1" class="js-gps-track" data-ga="[&quot;community bulletin board&quot;,&quot;Featured&quot;,&quot;https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/404909/stack-overflow-jobs-is-expanding-to-more-countries&quot;,null,null]" data-gps-track="communitybulletin.click({ priority: 3, position: 0, location: homepage })">Stack Overflow Jobs is expanding to more countries</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="s-sidebarwidget--item d-flex px16">
            <div class="flex--item1 fl-shrink0">
<div class="favicon favicon-stackexchangemeta" title="Meta Stack Exchange"></div>            </div>
            <div class="flex--item wmn0 ow-break-word">
                <a href="https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/404724/the-december-2024-community-asks-sprint-has-been-moved-to-march-2025-and-length?cb=1" class="js-gps-track" title="The December 2024 Community Asks Sprint has been moved to March 2025 (and lengthened to 2 weeks to compensate)" data-ga="[&quot;community bulletin board&quot;,&quot;Featured&quot;,&quot;https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/404724/the-december-2024-community-asks-sprint-has-been-moved-to-march-2025-and-length&quot;,null,null]" data-gps-track="communitybulletin.click({ priority: 3, position: 1, location: homepage })">The December 2024 Community Asks Sprint has been moved to March 2025 (and...</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

The other boxes on the right sidebar (e.g. "Custom Filters") use properly marked-up headers with <h2> tags. Please change the "Featured" header to use header markup. Screen reading software can't tell that the apparent list item should appear as a header, and thus it's read as another list item. As in, a list with three items, the first of which is "Featured". That means the page's markup is lying.

It doesn't look like that HTML complies with the Stacks Design System.
In Sidebar widgets the examples show:
<nav class="s-sidebarwidget">
    <h2 class="s-sidebarwidget--header">
        Personal Information
    </h2>
    <ul class="s-sidebarwidget--content s-sidebarwidget__items">
        <li class="s-sidebarwidget--item">
            <a href="…">
                …
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="s-sidebarwidget--item" aria-current="page">
            <a href="…">
                …
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <h2 class="s-sidebarwidget--header">
        Site Settings
    </h2>
    <ul class="s-sidebarwidget--content s-sidebarwidget__items">
        <li class="s-sidebarwidget--item">
            <a href="…">Preferences</a>
        </li>
        <li class="s-sidebarwidget--item">
            <a href="…">Flair</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

and there is even a warning for the correct use of the h2 element:

The examples of s-sidebarwidget--header are shown shown added to h2 elements in examples, but the appropriate heading level may differ depending on context. Please use the appropriate heading level for the context to ensure heading levels only increase by 1.

Nor the examples nor the warning seem to be adhered to. The current implementation hinders accessibility.
